# Pass parameters per reference from c++ to java via jni

Tags: java, c++, parameters, reference, java-native-interface

I'm trying to pass a variable from c++ to java per reference via JNI. For the beginning I've tried it with some simple code:

**Java**

```
public static void inc(int val) {
  System.out.println("inc called: " + val);
  val++;
}

public static void dec(int val) {
  System.out.println("dec called: " + val);
  val--;
```

}

This should simply in-/decrement a variable created in c++ code with a Java method.
The c++ part looks like this:

**C++**

```
jmethodID jDec = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "dec", "(I)V");
jmethodID jInc = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "inc", "(I)V");

jint val = 10;

printf("%d\n", val);
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, jDec, &val);
printf("%d\n", val);
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, jInc, val);
printf("%d\n", val);
```

As you see, I tried both, per reference and per value.

**Output**

```
10
dec called: -401031272
10
inc called: 10
10
```

Within the c++ code, the value is all the time 10, in Java it is either the address or the value.

Would be nice if you could give me a hint, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: This code doesn't even make sense just as pure C++. This isn't how functions work.

Comment: This code doesn't even make sense just as pure Java. This isn't how parameters work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Wojtek said, Java passes arguments by value. You can add a **return value** your Java code:

```
public static int inc2(int val) {
    System.out.println("inc called: " + val);
    return val + 1;
}
```

and then call it from C++:

```
jmethodID inc2 = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "inc2", "(I)I");
jint result = env->CallStaticIntMethod(cls, inc2, val);
printf("inc2: %d\n", result);
```

Another approach is to use a **wrapper class** instead:

```
public class IntWrapper {

    private int value;

    public IntWrapper(int value) {
        setInt(value);
    }

    public int getInt() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setInt(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

and the following Java method:

```
public static void inc3(IntWrapper val) {
    val.setInt(val.getInt()+1);
}
```

You can then call this from your C++ code:

```
// create wrapper object
jclass wrapper = env->FindClass("IntWrapper");
jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID(wrapper, "<init>", "(I)V");
jobject wrapperObject = env->NewObject(wrapper, constructor, val);

// print value before increment
jmethodID getInt = env->GetMethodID(wrapper, "getInt", "()I");
jint ret = env->CallIntMethod(wrapperObject, getInt);
printf("Wrapper value: %d\n", ret);

// call inc3
jmethodID inc3 = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "inc3", "(LIntWrapper;)V");
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, inc3, wrapperObject);

// print result
ret = env->CallIntMethod(wrapperObject, getInt);
printf("Wrapper value after increment: %d\n", ret);
```

Alternatively you could use an int[] instead of the wrapper class as suggested by Wojtek.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the following does not make sense even in a pure C++ context:

```
jint val = 10;
// ...
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, jDec, &val);
```

`&val` returns the address of the local variable `val`. This normally doesn't even compile in C++. Try it yourself:

```
int x = 10;
int y = &x; // error
```

The reason why it compiles here is `CallStaticVoidMethod` being a variadic function. It is declared like this:

```
void CallStaticVoidMethod(jclass clazz, jmethodID methodID, ...)
```

The `...` part at the end means "anything goes, but you are responsible if you pass anything which I cannot handle correctly at run-time."

So this approach is obviously doomed.

The actual problem, however, is the fact that **Java does not have references** in the C++ sense. Everything is passed by value; there is simply no equivalent to a C++ `int &` parameter.

However, Java has pointers, even though it mostly calls them, confusingly, "references". A Java `Integer` reference, for example, would be an `Integer *` in C++ (supposing the existence of an `Integer` class in C++). Naively, you could just change your methods' signatures to take `Integer` arguments and fiddle with the objects on the C++ side, but this won't work either, because Java's `Integer` class is immutable, so you cannot increment it.

So what can you really do?

You could leverage **1-element arrays**, but this is not a very nice solution; it increases the amount of error checking you have to do. To make your code robust enough, you'd have to make sure that the arrays do not contain 0 or > 1 elements. Additionally, arrays will confuse everyone who sees the code.

An alternative solution is to create your **own mutable integer class** and use that one. Something like this:

```
public class MutableInteger {

    private int value;

    public MutableInteger(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void increment() {
        ++value;
    }

    public void decrement() {
        --value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }

    public int get() {
        return value;
    }

    // other operations
}
```

(...)

```
public static void inc(MutableInteger val) {
  System.out.println("inc called: " + val);
  val.increment();
}
```

The C++ side of the code will be more complicated as a result of it. You will have to first find your class, find and call its constructor, find and call the `increment` method, then finally find and call the `get` method. Ideally, you wrap all of this in a small C++ function:

```
void increment(JNIEnv *env, int &value)
{
    jclass javaClass = env->FindClass(env, "your/package/MutableInteger");
    jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID(env, javaClass, "<init>", "(I)V");
    jobject javaObject = env->NewObject(env, javaClass, constructor, value);
    jmethodID incrementMethod = env->GetMethodID(env, javaClass, "increment", "()V");
    env->CallVoidMethod(javaObject, incrementMethod, value);
    jmethodID getMethod = env->GetMethodID(env, javaClass, "get", "()I");
    value = env->CallIntMethod(javaObject, getMethod);
}
```

(I've written this off the top of my head, so it may contain errors, and you should of course add a lot of error handling and possibly some `jmethodID` optimisations in real code.)

Is this worth the trouble? Probably not. It may be justifiable if the Java methods are also called from a lot of other Java code and you want to keep a consistent interface. If the Java methods are only called from C++ code, then the whole approach is nonsense, and the correct solution would then be to change the methods to instead **return the incremented value**:

```
public static int inc(int val) {
  System.out.println("inc called: " + val);
  return val + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"This should simply in-/decrement a variable created in c++ code with a Java method." no it shouldn't. Java passes arguments by value, so you are incrementing and decrementing not the C++ variable, but variable `val` local in functions `inc` and `dec`.

Comment: I want it to simply in-/decrement a variable. I know it's not working at the moment. That's why I'm here to ask for help. And yes, I know what the code is doing at the moment, but that's not what I need.

Comment: Use 1-element arrays instead of single ints.